# Angular2 - calling constructor() vs new keyword to create an object?

Tags: angular

I went through the Angular2 tutorial and i couldn't really understand the difference between something like:

```
constructor(private _heroService: HeroService) { }
```

and creating an object such as

`var _heroService: HeroService = new HeroService();`

could you clarify?

Answer (score 3):

Declaring an object as constructor argument makes it part of [`Dependency Injection`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html) system. It's typically used with services and insures that services are singletons.

Instantiating an object with `new` keyword is used to create objects that are not injectable, typically data models. It's also sometimes used when testing (simple) services.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor

```
constructor(private _heroService: HeroService) { }
```

is executed when

```
new SomeComponent();
```

is executed, where the constructor defines which parameters need to be passed to `new Xxx(...)`. For example:

```
new SomeComponent(new HeroService);
```

If a new instance is created by Angular `new Xxx(...)` is executed by Angulars DI, It figures out which parameters to pass automatically from the constructor.

If no constructor is defined the default constructor

```
constructor(){}
```

is automatically added to the class.

Comment: DI in angular 2 creates a Singleton instance. If we use `new` keyword instead of using DI, will it also create a Singleton instance? Just being curious.

Comment: @barnes no, `new` always just creates a new instance.