# Dependency Injection problem for creating dynamic components with ngComponentOutlet

Tags: angular, angular7

The project requires to create components dynamically by using ngComponentOutlet directive. The dynamic components will receive data by injecting it into the constructor. So, how can I pass this data as a parameter in the constructor?

I have created a sample and the link is 
 https://angular-lqaeqp.stackblitz.io/load

The project structure is:

1. HomeComponent - The starting point
2. LoadComponents Module - A lazy loaded module which has 2 components

   (i) LoadComponents - The default for route '/load'

   (ii) Component1Component - The dynamic component that will be created from LoadComponents

The LoadComponents has the following code for the creation:

`<ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="component;injector: injectData;"></ng-container>`

3. Content Model - A model that needs to be injected in Component1Component

If I remove the injection code then the app works, otherwise it shows the error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Component1Component -> Content]
```

For the time being I have solved the project issue by using the plugin "ng-dynamic-component", which works like a charm. But I have to apply Angular's  ngComponentOutlet directive.

Comment: Can you share stackblitz edit link?

Comment: I am sorry. Here it is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lqaeqp

Answer (score 1):

You are injecting `Content` to your component, therefore it should be an injectable:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Content {
    @Input() public Code: string;
    @Input() public HTML: string;
}
```

Your fixed **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fedj71?file=src/app/content.model.ts)**

*PS. Always include the troubling code in your question!*

Comment: it resolved the issue but as I am injecting the data from LoadComponent, the Component1 is not showing the data but just a blank object. I understood that it will inject a new instance of Content but I want its property filled from LoadComponet.

Answer (score 1):

Service and Component are different purpose in Angular

> Service is a broad category encompassing any value, function, or
>   feature that an app needs. A service is typically a class with a
>   narrow, well-defined purpose. It should do something specific and do
>   it well.
>
> Angular distinguishes components from services to increase modularity
>   and reusability. By separating a component's view-related
>   functionality from other kinds of processing, you can make your
>   component classes lean and efficient.

Since you are Using Injectable decorator inside content.module.ts you should not use 
@Input decorator. Then don't initialize Object with new Key word. Instantiating an object with new keyword is used to create objects that are not injectable.
Ref:[Angular2 - calling constructor() vs new keyword to create an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423103/angular2-calling-constructor-vs-new-keyword-to-create-an-object)

**content.model.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';    
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class Content {
   Code: string ;
   HTML: string;
}
```

Example:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-favvmz

Comment: Thank you, this got resolved. I injected the Content model in another component then it shows blank object. I expected previous values would be preserved in this model object as DI uses Singleton!!!

Comment: In which component did you injected?

Comment: I tried in my local repo. My bad, I added the component in the wrong module. After adding the component in the LoadComponents module indeed the injected model is same for all.

Comment: Check this if you are trying to share singleton across application using lazy loading: https://alligator.io/angular/providers-shared-modules/